# why does LESS prints out arithmetic operations as text?

Tags: html, css, less

When i'm writing the following operations

```
@a: 2px

@variable: @a + 5;

.margin-style{

margin-left: @variable;

}
```

This above code compiles to

```
.margin-style{
margin-left: 2px + 5;
}
```

instead of

```
margin-left:7px;
```

What seems to be going wrong?

Comment: Which version and do you use any extra setting? On lesstester.com, it compiles to `margin-left: 7px`.

Comment: @Harry using the latest version of LESS, just downloaded the bootstrap source and made modifications inside bootstrap.less. Any special conditions under which this happens?

Comment: @variable: @a + 5px  outputs -> margin-left: 2px + 5px

Comment: everything just keeps printing out "as is"

Comment: Does putting the whole thing within braces (like `(@a + 5px)`) solve the problem? If yes, maybe you have strict math turned on. (Note that by default the strict math option is off)

Comment: @Harry The braces solved it.  Perhaps all arithmetic operations must be enclosed? Thanks!

Comment: You must have modified some setting to turn it on mate because by default it is off. And yes, when it is on, you need to put all arithmetic operations within braces for them to be treated as one. Everything outside will be output as though they are text.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72505/discussion-between-wolfgang-and-harry).

Answer (score 0):

Using Bootstrap and Grunt

setting `strictMath:false` in the `Gruntfile.js` under the less compiler settings solved the issue